# Container has different rules for .net 5 web app and test project

Tags: dryioc

I have a small .net 5 WebApi app, using DryIoc. I am now trying to set up an xUnit test suite for this app, but the integration tests fail immediately because one of the registrations has multiple constructors, even though I am using the same rules for both containers and running the same registrations in the same order as the app.

The registration works fine for the app because the container has `ConstructorWithResolvableArguments` set for the factory method, but it's not being set from anywhere in our code. I know I can easily just add that rule to the container for the tests, but I don't understand why a container set up in the exact same way appears to have different rules, and I am concerned there may be other differences that could affect the tests.

In the app, the container is set up like so:

`Program.cs`

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new DryIocServiceProviderFactory(Startup.CreateContainer()))
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(...);
```

`StartUp.cs`

```
...
public static IContainer CreateContainer() => new Container(DiConfiguration.SetRules);

public void ConfigureContainer(IContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterCoreDependencies();

    // Site specific registrations
    container.ConfigureDomain();
}
```

`DiConfiguration.cs`

```
public static class DiConfiguration
{
    public static Rules SetRules(Rules rules)
    {
        rules = rules.WithAutoConcreteTypeResolution();
        rules = rules.WithVariantGenericTypesInResolve();

        return rules;
    }

    public static void RegisterCoreDependencies(this IContainer container)
    {
        // dependency registrations, not much to see here, nothing clever 
        // just basic registrations e.g.

        container.Register<IFoo, Foo>();
    }
```

In the test suite I am setting up the container like so:

```
public class Test
{
    private object _sut;

    public Test()
    {
        var container = new Container(DiConfiguration.SetRules); // <--- Same rules as the app
        container.RegisterCoreDependencies(); // <--- fails here
        container.ConfigureDomain();

        _sut = container.Resolve<Bar>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Some_Test_Here()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, all the container registration code is abstracted out into a shared library (the `DiConfiguration` class). The test is failing calling `RegisterCoreDependencies`. I don't understand why the rules are different between the two scenarios, is it perhaps something introduced by the `DryIocServiceProviderFactory` call in the app setting some extra defaults? (`DryIocServiceProviderFactory` is part of the `DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DryIocServiceProviderFactory` will override the existing container rules to conform to MS.DI container. Here is the code:  https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/5e3f1f7edfe237f69ba33c9166d17e284ca4781a/src/DryIoc.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/DryIocAdapter.cs#L97

Here how the rules are overriden in detail:

```cs
private static Rules WithMicrosoftDependencyInjectionRules(Rules rules) 
{ 
    rules = rules.Clone(cloneMade: true);

    rules._settings |= Settings.TrackingDisposableTransients;
    rules._settings &= ~Settings.ThrowOnRegisteringDisposableTransient;
    rules._settings &= ~Settings.VariantGenericTypesInResolvedCollection;
    rules._factorySelector = SelectLastRegisteredFactory;
    rules._made._factoryMethod = DryIoc.FactoryMethod.ConstructorWithResolvableArguments;
 
    return rules; 
}
```

Comment: Ah makes sense. Thought it would be something like that, thanks